# give category id to subcategory in laravel seed

Tags: laravel, seed

I try to add data with seed in laravel 5.4, let's say I have 10 category and I added them by seed to my database now I also have another seed for subcategories but before I add my subcategories I want to tell which one is belongs to what category that I imported before. how would I do that?

Update:

I found my question might be confusing for some people so i try to explain a bit more,

this is my `category` seed.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CategoriessTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('categories')->delete();

        $categories = array(
            array('name' => 'Accounting/Finance', 'slug' => 'hccounting_finance'),
            array('name' => 'Admin/Human Resources', 'slug' => 'admin_human_resources'),
            array('name' => 'Arts/Media/Communications', 'slug' => 'arts_media_communications'),
            array('name' => 'Building/Construction', 'slug' => 'building_construction'),
            array('name' => 'Computer/Information Technology', 'slug' => 'computer_information_technology'),
            array('name' => 'Education/Training', 'slug' => 'education_training'),
            array('name' => 'Engineering', 'slug' => 'engineering'),
            array('name' => 'Healthcare', 'slug' => 'healthcare'),
            array('name' => 'Hotel/Restaurant', 'slug' => 'hotel_restaurant'),
            array('name' => 'Manufacturing', 'slug' => 'manufacturing'),
            array('name' => 'Sales/Marketing', 'slug' => 'sales_marketing'),
            array('name' => 'Sciences', 'slug' => 'sciences'),
            array('name' => 'Services', 'slug' => 'services'),
            array('name' => 'Others', 'slug' => 'others'),
        );

        DB::table('categories')->insert($categories);
    }
}
```

I have another similar with this for subcategories here it is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class SubategoriessTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('subcategories')->delete();

        $subcategories = array(
            array('name' => 'Audit & Taxation Jobs', 'slug' => 'audit_taxation_jobs', 'category_id' => ''),
        );

        DB::table('subcategories')->insert($subcategories);
    }
}
```

in this sample `'category_id' => ''` has to get the id/name of `'Accounting/Finance` category in `category seed` .

now my question is how?

UPDATE 2:

Error's

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails (`jobid`.`ads`, CONSTRAINT `ads_subcateg 
>   ory_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategory_id`) REFERENCES
>   `subcategories` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `subcategories`)
>
> ```
>  [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> ```
>
> (`jobid`.`ads`, CONSTRAINT `ads_subcateg
>         ory_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategory_id`) REFERENCES `subcategories` (`id`))

Code used:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class SubcategoriesTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('subcategories')->delete();


            $categoryFinance = Category::select("id")->whereSlug("hccounting_finance")->firstOrFail();
            $subcategories = array(
             array('name' => 'Audit & Taxation Jobs', 'category_id' => $categoryFinance,  'slug' => 'audit_taxation_jobs', 'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
             array('name' => 'Banking/Financial Jobs', 'category_id' => $categoryFinance, 'slug' => 'banking-financial_jobs', 'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
             array('name' => 'Corporate Finance/Investment Jobs', 'category_id' => $categoryFinance, 'slug' => 'corporate_finance_investment_jobs', 'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
             array('name' => 'General/Cost Accounting Jobs', 'category_id' => $categoryFinance, 'slug' => 'general_cost_accounting_jobs', 'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
         );

         $categoryAdmin = Category::select("id")->whereSlug("admin_human_resources")->firstOrFail();
         $subcategories = array(
            array('name' => 'testing', 'slug' => 'tesingsubs', 'category_id' => $categoryAdmin, 'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
        );

        DB::table('subcategories')->insert($subcategories);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are seeding your subcategories data, then in each insert/create query you can defind which subcategory it belongs to. Also please elaborate on you problem.

Comment: You can seed them both together to make this easier. Seed the category and get the collection of categories at the same time and then for each category seed sub categories. This can be done easily with collection. Check out this example to give you a good idea https://github.com/gothinkster/laravel-realworld-example-app/blob/master/database/seeds/DummyDataSeeder.php

Comment: updated my question would you look at it please?

Answer (score 0):

In order to relate your categories to subcategories, you should follow the logic (depending on your relationship - N-1 N-N) in the docs  (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships). It seems that you need the attach() method.

So after creating the category entry, if you have followed the schema convention you can apply logic for all kind or relationships, even for polymorphic ones.

***Edit:***

After your edit it seems that you need a way to access the entries of your table again in order to relate them.

So, you can :

```
$categoryFinance = Category::select("id")->whereSlug("hccounting_finance")->firstOrFail();
```

in your SubategoriessTableSeeder run() function before creating your array.

And then give that id in your subcategory_id. The same will be for all categories you need to relate.

***Edit 2***

Please check again that your foreign keys are correct. In that case you cannot delete the subcategories table because Categories "need" subid. And that's where constraint violation comes from. You don't need to delete these tables.. You just need to "feed-seed" them.

So try to remove the "delete" statements.

***Edit 3***

I think the error is obvious now.. There is no Category with id of 2 in your database. But again, check if the keys are associated correctly (this is an SQL and not a Laravel issue).

Run migrations if any, and seeders again, with the correct order (first categories and then subcategories - first the dependency and then the dependent one in general)

Comment: @loannis I've updated my code with your suggestion perhaps I made mistakes, please see my question update.

Comment: I deleted `delete` but still get error     `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ("jobid"."subcategories", CONSTRAINT "subcat
  egories_category_id_foreign:" FOREIGN KEY ("category_id") REFERENCES "categories" ("id")) (SQL: insert into "subcategories" ("category_id", "created_at", "name", "s
  lug", "updated_at") values ({"id":2}, 2017-06-09 07:26:06, testing, tesingsubs, 2017-06-09 07:26:06))`